# Compare two tables and store result in third table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database.

I want to compare the each row of `email` of `table-1` with the each row of `email2` of `table-2` if their content matches then I want to store the `mac` of `table-1` to `Mac` of `Result table`.

This is table-1

```
Email    Mac
value1 21321
value2 45666
```

This is table-2

```
Name   email2
name1  xyyxas
name2  xxxxxx
```

This is Result Table

```
ID      Mac
1     21321
2     45666
```

I am completely out of logic here I tried join queries but they doesn't seem to be fit in my case.

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: given that table-1 and table-2 have no values in common, exactly HOW are you expecting us to figure out how to produce the result table?

Comment: @MarcB they have email's  which may be common , so i need a logic here through which i can compare each row of email of table1 with each row of email of table-2

Comment: if your going to provide fake sample data, at least make that fake sample data make sense

Comment: How do you get those results from the input data you showed? Why is `21321` in the `Result` table when it doesn't match in the input tables?

Comment: then I suggest you go read up about [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)s

Comment: This is one of the most simple types of joins there is. Please show what you tried so we can help you understand what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a insert select with inner join

```
insert into result_table (mac)
select table1.mac from table1 
inner join table2 on table1.email = table2.email
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO RESULT
(MAC)
SELECT A.MAC 
FROM table1 as A
inner join table2 as B
on A.Email = B.Email2
```

Please Refer following link for Inner Join and how it works

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Following Image represent how JOIN works.

[image]

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I am a new user. I recently start answering. Now on I will explain the reason too. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: That isn't my DV, but explanations are what make an answer a good answer. For a newbie with no knowledge of basic inner joins this will be like rocket science without an explanation. Code only answers are usually down voted more quickly that yours has been, that is why I gave you the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

This is Simple. First you Join your table using the common column, in your case the `email` column. Once they are joined, you collect the data required, in your case the `mac` column on table 1. One this is done you `insert` it to your table 3. This is my approach:

```
INSERT INTO tbl3(mac) 
SELECT t1.mac 
FROM tbl1 AS t1
JOIN tbl2 AS t2
ON t1.email = t2.email
```