# Computed Column (Microsoft SQL Server 2014)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, calculated-columns, computed-field

**Book**

```
| B_ID |   Name  | Unit_Price|
|------+---------+-----------|
|  B01 |   Math  |     25    |
|  B02 | Science |     34    |
```

**Order**

```
| O_ID | B_ID |  Quantity |Total_Price|
|------+------+-----------+-----------|
|  O01 |  B01 |     2     |     ?     |
|  O02 |  B02 |     5     |     ?     |
```

How can I get the **Total_Price** by multiplying `Order.Quantity` and `Book.Unit_Price` where `Order.B_ID` is a FK to `Book.B_ID`. Thank you!

Comment: Check the image in this link. You will have clear idea of Joins. Which will help you to understand this type of queries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35349303/php-compare-two-tables-and-store-result-in-third-table/35349429#35349429

Comment: @Mytroy2050 thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function where the computed column would use the function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetTotalPrice(INT @id)
RETURNS DECIMAL(19,4)
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @ret DECIMAL(19,4)
   SELECT @ret = O.Quantity * B.Unit_Price
                 FROM Order O
                   INNER JOIN Book B
                   ON O.B_ID = B.B_ID
                     WHERE B.B_ID = @id
          IF (@ret IS NULL)   
             SET @ret = 0
          RETURN @ret
END

ALTER TABLE dbo.Order
   ADD Total_Price AS dbo.GetTotalPrice(O_ID)
```

Comment: Why do I get 0.0000 for all the Total_Price? I followed your code, but I only changed the 1st line to: CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetTotalPrice(@id VARCHAR(5))

Comment: Probably because @ret is null. Are you passing the correct id? Try running the query alone.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds more like you need to create a `VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.OrderPrice
AS

SELECT O.O_ID,
       O.B_ID,
       O.Quantity,
       O.Quantity * B.Unit_Price Total_Price
FROM Order O
INNER JOIN Book B
    ON O.B_ID = B.B_ID;
```